# GWT:How to access java variable from JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have this method:

```
public void testJSNI2(){
  String x = "test";
}
```

I can access this method like this:

```
helloJsni.@com.jsni.client.HelloJSNIImpl::testJSNI2(Ljava/lang/String;)
```

But how can I access the String `x`, which is defined inside a method?

Comment: Why would anyone vote this question down. Is this site only for people who have an expert knowledge in the subject they are asking? If they had an expert knowledge, would they even need to ask? Stop being trigger happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the variable `x` because it is in the scope of the method, the same way you wouldn't be able to access it in Java code.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not correct. JavaScript and Java dose not act the same.
Person can access any field from js with the help of JSNI:

```
public class JSNIExample {

  String myInstanceField;
  static int myStaticField;

  void instanceFoo(String s) {
    // use s
  }

  static void staticFoo(String s) {
    // use s
  }

  public native void bar(JSNIExample x, String s) /*-{
    // Call instance method instanceFoo() on this
    this.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::instanceFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Call instance method instanceFoo() on x
    x.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::instanceFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Call static method staticFoo()
    @com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::staticFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Read instance field on this
    var val = this.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myInstanceField;

    // Write instance field on x
    x.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myInstanceField = val + " and stuff";

    // Read static field (no qualifier)
    @com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myStaticField = val + " and stuff";
  }-*/;

}
```

You can see this here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html